# How to refer JSX file to an HTML Page

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have referred JSX file in HTML Page and the page is not displaying any content.

HTML (Index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="https://***/react-15.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://***/react-dom-15.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSX (Script.js)

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I have  tried change the file extension to .jsx/.js and still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use babel-standalone to transpile your JSX code. Also use text/babel in script type

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="https://***/react-15.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://***/react-dom-15.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

However I will recommend you to use `webpack` to transpile you code with the use of babel-loader

Comment: Shubham -  I had tried referring the JSX transpiler and still no luck. If I embed JSX into the html, it works.

Comment: Do you mean that you are not able to configure webpack, and when does it work